Error Function is_tax was called incorrectly
I am developing for a client, and everything was working fine until I ran into this error:
Notice: Function is_tax was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
I am not sure what this means. Could this be a symptom of lazy loading? I tried disabling all of my plugins and reinstalling them. I even tried restoring a backup from the day before and still had this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Somewhere in the codebase, the function or method is_tax() is being called before WordPress knows what content is being requested. Using a plugin like Query Monitor will help determine it's source. There may also be a stack trace in wp-content/debug.log (if WordPress is setup with debug constants).
This would not be a symptom of lazy loading (for images). This error is coming from PHP. It could be coming from an AJAX request, but that seems unlikely.
